# Why does my mask move when I zoom?

Tags: masking

I created a mask in blender, but it moves around when I zoom in and out. For different zoom levels, the mask appears in a different location. Is this a bug in blender? Or is there some way to prevent this behavior?

Here is my mask at 2:1 zoom:
[image: Mask at 2:1 zoom]

At 1:1 zoom (notice that the mask moved down and to the left):
[image: Mask at 1:1 zoom]

At 1:2 zoom:
[image: Mask at 1:2 zoom]

At 1:8 zoom (the mask is no longer surrounding the subject):
[image: Mask at 1:8 zoom]

### System Information

Arch Linux x86_64, NVIDIA GeForce GTX 560 Ti

Also reproducible on OS X 10.11, NVIDIA GeForce GT 750M

Blender Version 2.78c

### Minimal working example

[image]

Minimal working movie clip: [GOPR1630.mov](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ua2lxfrxechz8us/GOPR1630.mov?dl=1)

On my machine, zooming out will cause the mask to move from its original position. Without the referenced GOPR1630.mov, unselecting and then selecting "Display Stabilization" in the movie clip editor will fix the problem. However, if the GOPR1630.mov file exists, zooming will cause the mask to move whenever "Display Stabilization" is selected.

The amount of mask movement when zooming seems proportional to how much the track point for image stabilization (Track.002) moves.

Comment: Thanks @cegaton , I've added a minimal working example to the question, but the behavior is a bit different with and without the my movie clip. Is there an easy way to attach my movie clip to the question?

Comment: I see what you mean now. I do not understand why it does that, but can you elaborate on what you are trying to do and what you are planing to do with the mask? Why do you need to display it over the stabilized footage? You can use the tracker and parent the mask to one or more tracking points so that it is anchored to fixed points on the image, or you can use the mask over the stabilized video using the compositor.

Comment: While I doubt it is related to the video I do expect it is a bug. Does the mask actually move if you use it in the compositor? or is it only the mask display in the clip editor when zooming with stabilization on?

Comment: Thanks guys, I've added more information on what I'm intending to do into the question body. Suggestions on better ways to approach the problem are welcome. Also happy to break it out into a separate question if that would be more appropriate. @sambler the mask is not where I expect it to be in the compositor, but it could just be that the mask is not aligned properly with the time delayed footage.

Comment: please break down your additional questions on different posts, so far looks like the issue with the mask and zooming on the window is some form of bug. For other questions please make a new post to keep things organized.

Comment: I've rolled back the question to focus on the original problem and submitted a blender bug report (T51388).